# Get Unread messages count from Chatter Rest API

Tags: chatter

Trying to do something that seems like it would be simple but its giving me more trouble that i would have thought.

I want to grab just a count of unread private messages the user had to display.

I see this endpoint but that seems to grab all the messages with no indication of read/unread
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_users_messages_general.htm?search_text=messages

is there another place i should look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?

```
GET /chatter/users/<userId>/conversations/unread-count
```

API doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_users_unread_conversations.htm